# phpmyadmin - Error in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to execute the following query without any luck. It says:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 32

I am unable to point out any errors. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE PROCEDURE `Acc_Ledger`(IN `startDate` VARCHAR(200), IN `endDate` VARCHAR(200), IN `p_id` INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE RunningTotal, deb, cred DECIMAL(19,2);
    DECLARE counter, row_count int;

    SET RunningTotal = 0;
    SET counter = 1;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LedgerTbl;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE LedgerTbl (CTR int primary key auto_increment, PARTY_ID INT,VRDATE VARCHAR(200),VRNOA VARCHAR(200),ETYPE VARCHAR(50),DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(500),DEBIT DECIMAL(19,2),CREDIT DECIMAL(19,2),RTotal DECIMAL(19,2));

    INSERT INTO LedgerTbl
    SELECT null, PARTY_ID,VRDATE,DCNO,ETYPE,DESCRIPTION,DEBIT,CREDIT, null FROM pledger WHERE PARTY_ID=p_id AND DATE(VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate 
    ORDER BY VRDATE,ETYPE,DCNO;

    SET @RunningTotal := 0;

    SELECT SUM(DEBIT)-SUM(CREDIT) FROM pledger WHERE DATE(VRDATE) < startDate AND party_id = p_id INTO @RunningTotal;

    IF ISNULL(@RunningTotal) THEN
        SET @RunningTotal := 0;
    END IF;

    UPDATE LedgerTbl 
    SET RTotal = (@RunningTotal := @RunningTotal + (DEBIT - CREDIT));

    SELECT * FROM LedgerTbl;
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed

```
DELIMITER ;
```

at the end of query. Added this and everything is working fine.